# Get "Calling thread must be STA" when making a new dialog window using MVVM Light messages

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light

I have a dialog window that is shown when a message is recived in my Views View-Model

The Dialog is as here http://pastebin.com/BAeCLwhz (I know I should have a empty codebehind, but making it empty is second priority, so that is not an issue now!)

I create the window in my Projects View-Model with

```
MessengerInstance.Register<bool>(this, "Homing", ShowHomingDialog);

private void ShowHomingDialog(bool b)
    {
        HomingRobot hb = new HomingRobot();
        hb.ShowDialog();
    }
```

But when its run I get "Calling thread must be STA" I tried calling the dialog on the projects codebehind instead of in the viewmodel, but that gave me the same result. So how am I supposed to make my window pop up without it being "multithreaded" is that even possible when using messages?

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the ShowDialog code in the Dispatcher.Invoke as shown below

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    HomingRobot hb = new HomingRobot();        
    hb.ShowDialog();
}));
```

If the above code doesn't work, you can try the following

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    HomingRobot hb = new HomingRobot();        
    hb.ShowDialog();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "dispatch" your UI work to the UI thread.

See this tip http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Tip-Asynchronous-Silverlight-Execute-on-the-UI-thread.aspx

Comment: Is it the creating of my dialog I have to create a in a dispatcher? And if yes, do I then just do begin invoke and then it "finds" the UI thread?

Comment: It's probably the `hb.ShowDialog()` that you need to dispatch and yest it, finds the thread. Do some googling on Dispatcher.